# Hibernate - how to fetch properties for list of objects in one query

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, lazy-loading

I have Persistent class, referring to many collections with LAZY fetch type, like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class Table implements Serializable {
    ....


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST1", nullable = true)
    private ArrayList list1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST2", nullable = true)
    private ArrayList list2;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST1", nullable = true)
    private ArrayList list1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST2", nullable = true)
    private ArrayList list2;

....
```

}

I have instantiated some objects of type TABLE through Hibernate, added it to a list of Tables, and now want to fetch one of this collections (say list2) for all objects in this list.

```
for(Table table:tables){
     result=table.list2;
     ....
}
```

But this way Hibernate will generate sequence of separate SQL queries. Can hibernate fetch list2 for all the objects in collection in one query? (It is important not to create new Table class instances, but modify objects, that are already exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be
>   initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.
>   This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It
>   effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the
>   mapping file for associations and collections.

```
select t from Table t
left join fetch t.list2
where ...
```

Comment: As I understand, this will create new collection of object, but my objective is to modify existent objects

Comment: Hibernate only keeps one instance of a given entity in its cache. If you query for entities that are already loaded in the cache, these entities will be returned by the query. Except that their collection will be initialized thanks to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You should map list2 property with generics. Lets say:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class Table implements Serializable {
    ....


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST1", nullable = true)
    private List<OtherClass> list1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LIST2", nullable = true)
    private List<OtherClass> list2;
}
```

HQL query for that:

```
select list2 from Table
```

So lets say you are using hibernate template to fetch data:

```
List<OtherClass> result = getHibernateTemplate().find("select list2 from Table");
```

Comment: No, this is not a valid HQL query. And even if it was, you could not tell which list belongs to which table, and there is no way it returns a List<ArrayList>

Comment: It is valid HQL query. Of course it will not work in this example because class provided by user1160344 is invalid. You are right that List<ArrayList> is wrong in here. When list2 would be correctly mapped property with type List<T> result should be List<T>

Comment: Thank you, but this in not the way in my case: The main objective is to modify existent objects, not to create new objects with those collections fetched

Comment: In my case you dont fetch Table objects again but only objects from list2 property.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just checked and it's indeed valid HQL. It's not valid JPQL, though.